# Mechanic detected low coolant level in car, says no leaks, could some of it have evaporated slowly over time?

Tags: vw, coolant, coolant-leak, polo

I'm looking to buy a second-hand VW Polo 1.2 TSI, 2015, and with 31K miles on the clock (I'm based in the UK). Car has clean history, never written off and has passed all its MOTs without any advisories.

I hired a mechanic through ClickMechanic to inspect it and a couple of things came up which dealer said they would address. But the one that's really giving me pause is the low coolant level. On the report I got from the mechanic it only says "Coolant level is low , needs top up". The coolant leaks section comes up as in working order, so presumably no leaks spotted. I followed up with him and he said:

> I didn’t notice any smoke or leaks. Is just little under the the minimum .
> There is a minimum and maximum marks on the coolant reservoir .

So not sure what to think. I tried following up with the mechanic but he's not responding to any further messages. Dealer says car has no leaks and that this is covered by the warranty.

Is it normal for the coolant to go down in any other circumstances, eg, if it's never been topped up and it just very, very slowly evaporated over the years?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was there any indication, through receipts or what have you, that the engine coolant has ever been changed?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hi! I didn't see any, so will follow up with the dealer about that, worth checking.